# How to update ui in background without losing ui responsiveness?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make ui responsive all the time and do background updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133731/how-to-make-ui-responsive-all-the-time-and-do-background-updating)

Hi All,

I am creating a application which displays 8 thumbnails per page and it can have n pages. Each of these thumbnails are UIViews and are added to UIScrollView. However i have implemented Paging using the Apple sample code.

The prob:

1. Each thumbnail(UIView) takes 150
   millisecs to be created and added to
   scroll view
2. Hence for 3 pages it takes awful
   huge time to be created and added to
   the UI Scrollview.
3. At this point the scroll view is not very respsonsive and it is very jerky and gives a bad user experience
4. How can i create the thumbnails and add them to UIScrollview without affecting the touch responsiveness? I want them to run independent of the main thread which is resposible for handling touch events (i suppose).

Also i would like to mention that when a thumbnail is created i trigger a Async download of the image and the delegate method is called when download is complete.

Let me know the the options i have to make this more responsive and update UI without affecting the touch operations. The page control works fine with lazy loading of the grid of thumbnails.

TIA,

Praveen S

Comment: Please post more details on just what is done to create each UIView that makes it take 150 ms.

Comment: Each uiview consists of 8 sub uiviews. They have a thumbnail and 2 buttons each. Each thumnail is placed over a background image. Please update your answer on this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133731/how-to-make-ui-responsive-all-the-time-and-do-background-updating