# scrollViewDidScroll delegate is invoking automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am using scrollViewDidScroll delegate in my application.

But, many times, even though I dint start scrolling, this delegate is getting invoked which is creating a lot of problem. I heard that even when contentSize for a particular scroll view is set then at that time also this delegate i.e., `scrollViewDidScroll` will invoke.

What are the different scenarios in which this delegate gets invoked. What are the steps to control this?

Can I set any parameter to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scrollViewDidScroll also gets invoked when the orientation changes. This I came to know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8141423/1410561). This was the problem I was facing. And now my problem solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123991/uiscrollview-disable-scrolling-while-rotating-iphone-ipad) post.

Answer (score 10):

To prevent `scrollDidScroll:` from firing automatically when the view is loaded and adjusted, I waited to add my `UIScrollView` `delegate` until after all the views load using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is working well for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // add table view delegate after the views have been laid out to prevent scrollViewDidScroll
    // from firing automaticly when the view is adjusted on load, which makes the tab bar disappear 
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854739/my-app-calls-scrollviewdidscroll-19-times)

> scrollViewDidScroll: gets called every time the scroll bounds change.
>   This means it gets called during the scroll, as well as when it
>   starts. You may want to try scrollViewWillBeginDragging: instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know if `scrollDidScroll` was triggered manually (through finger gesters) or due to other events like `didSelect` or `setContentOffset`, use the `UIScrollView.isTracking` and `UIScrollView.isDecelerating` properties.

Example usage:

```
if scrollView.isTracking || scrollView.isDecelerating {
    scrollPosition = collectionView.contentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set UICollectionView, UITableView delegate here in this method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     // This method is called only after all subviews are laid
}
```